# WinForm компоненты .NET или OpenSource(конструктор схем)

Tags: c#, winforms, .net, блок-схема

Доброго времени суток. Есть ли какие-нибудь компоненты или примерные open source проекты для создания WinForm приложений .NET C# или уже реализованные проекты OpenSource.

Как мне кажется, в явном виде реализованных проектов(open source) не должно быть много, но хотя бы какие-то наброски или части проектов, возможно, кто-то в сети выкладывал.
Данная схема(чертеж) показывает работу подстанции с различным набором использованных частей: 
 - трансформаторы
 - регуляторы
 - шины
 - и т.д

[image]
p.s. Мне не обязательно нужен полностью реализованный проект. Достаточно и наброска, в котором был бы конструктор таких схем без излишеств. В нем нужна панель с набором различных элементов, которые как в Visio можно "перетаскивать" на рабочую область, чтобы потом их соединять и создавать общую схему. В последствие, чтобы можно было её сохранять в XML и потом подгружать.

Comment: Обязательно C#? Если нет, то можно посоветовать посмотреть на xcircuit.

Comment: Ну как раз C# и нужет - остальные реализации я то уже видел, в моем случае, я видел похожую штуку на WPF - компания "nevron" что-то такое разрабатывает.

Comment: WPF хорош тем, что на нём легче разрабатывать графические компоненты _с нуля_. Однако если есть уже готовая open-source-программа на другом языке, может, проще будет взять её?

Comment: Я с Вами полностью согласен. Только вот вопрос: если ли open source проект WPF для такого случая? Я видел только для создания обычных диаграмм и схем. Можно, конечно, переделать(что по всей видимости я и буду делать), но если есть уже реализованные варианты, хотелось бы узнать о них, да и других людей заинтересовало бы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реализации подобной задачи (схема тех.процесса) использовал в свое время [**вот этот вот компонент**](http://www.dataweb.de/en/products/diagramming.html) (он же на [**codeplex**](http://nshape.codeplex.com)). Называется он NShape и в использовании достаточно удобен.